# How to auto start an activiti workflow periodically in a certain schedule in Alfresco 5.0.c?

Tags: timer, workflow, alfresco, activiti

I created a custom review and approve activiti workflow. I need to start this workflow automatically in every certain period , say every 30 minutes. For this i used timer start event as below:

```
    <startEvent id="timerStart" name="Timer start" activiti:formKey="scheduledtask:submitParallelReviewTask">
        <timerEventDefinition>
           <timeCycle>R5/PT30M</timeCycle>
       </timerEventDefinition>
    </startEvent>
```

This created new process instance in every 30 minutes and repetition occured 5 times as required. But in the new timer started processes' tasks ,  initiator and other process variables were null. Also if i set the process variables as mandatory, timer executor job failed.

How can i set the initiator and other mandatory process variables in the newly created i.e. timer auto started process instances and its respective tasks?

Please suggest how to fix these bugs.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess for the solution you should use cron job of alfresco.

For using cron job you can find below link usefull.

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Scheduled_Actions

Use workflowService for setting parameters.

Comment: There's already a timer start event using which alfresco automatically creates a job to create a new process instance. So there is no other way around to set the workflow parameters of the newly created instance? Is using "workflowService" the only way to do this?

Comment: Well,I guess this is the good approach , because in future if you need to add some thing more.WorklfowService will have many things available.